# Wordpress multiple slugs for a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, slug

A custom post type can be registered with one slug (e.g. products)

```
register_post_type('products', $args);
```

How can I add multiple slugs to the same Custom Post Type?

```
website_address.com/en/products/
website_address.com/fr/produits/
website_address.com/it/prodotti/
```

Comment: Same question? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71974/using-same-slug-with-multiple-post-types

Comment: No, I need only one post type but with multiple slugs. Maybe URL rewriting?

Comment: Anyone ever find out the answer to this, I don't need the slug to be translated I actually need multiple rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite argument for `register_post_type()` accepts an array. One of the array keys is `slug`. So you could i18n it like this:

```
register_post_type( 
    'products', 
    array (
        'rewrite' => array (
            'slug' => _x( 'products', 'URL slug', 'your_text_domain' )
        )
    )
);
```

Idea taken from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/65951/22599).

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type