# Multiple Slugs for single Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to get a single custom post type to have multiple archive slugs.

Current rewrite:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blog/authors', 'with_front' => false ),
```

I'm looking to have multiple listings under the same CPT. I'm looking for this sort of functionality:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => array('blog/authors', 'our-people'), 'with_front' => false ),
```

Is this possible? I am currently assuming I'm going to have to write some custom rewrite rules although I was hoping for a clean solution.

From my searching I found these links but none are helpful for my situation:

https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/custom-post-type-with-multiple-slugs
Not helpful

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-rewrite-slugs-for-one-post-type
No fix

[Wordpress multiple slugs for a Custom Post Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533210/wordpress-multiple-slugs-for-a-custom-post-type)
Language specific.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite the post type url on page load after checking the URL using a hook:

```
register_post_type( 
    'products', 
    array (
        'rewrite' => array (
            'slug' => _x( 'products', 'URL slug', 'your_text_domain' )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an example of how this works based on your original problem? How did you get the slug to be both blog/authors and our-people?

Comment: I believe what I did was check the URL based on `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and if it contained the keywords I rewrote it to the new url. I hope this helps mate at least a little!